# laravel - update database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created an app in Laravel. In the beginning, I made a migration with the following content:

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('kundens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');       
        $table->string('vorname');
        $table->string('nachname');
        $table->string('strasse');
        $table->integer('plz');
        $table->string('wohnort');
        $table->string('mail');
        $table->integer('telefon');
        $table->string('geburtsdatum');

    });
}
```

No I want to add some tables like kaufpreis or "modernisierung". I added them under the other tables but when I save the file and write in the terminal I get the error:

> nothing to migrate.

So now how can I add some tables for more information?

Comment: Maybe try `php artisan migrate:fresh` - also, each table should have its own migration

Comment: You can either rollback and refresh the migrations (losing any data you would already have, so if the app is in production, DO NOT DO THIS), or create a new migration for the new tables.

Comment: php artisan migrate:refresh should do the same rolling back the migrations and calling the migrate function when done.

Comment: ahhh - the data are gone. What can i do in productive?

Comment: Create a new migration instead, and add the new tables there.

Comment: Well you have learnt (on harder way) that you need to backup data any time when you mess around with DB.

Comment: @Tpojka Yes! That was the hardest way to learn :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a new migration for `kaufpreis` and `modernisierung`.

The main migration for `kundens` did already run (see `migrations` table).

---

`php artisan migrate:fresh` is also an option, if you are developing locally.

**Don't do this when you work with other people / production** as it will erase the tables and create new ones (data will be lost)

Comment: ahh ok i understand. When i now make a new migration for that the other will not deleted - the new migration just add them?

Comment: @DierigPatrick That's right. The `migration table` keeps track of which migration has run. When you create a new migration php artisan knows this migration has not run before and will run it.

Comment: Thank you very much - a new small milestone in laravel developing. I love laravel and love that whole community on stackoverflow. Thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: No problem, enjoy your day :)